# Automating android emulator and browser using Appium script

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, appium

Performing automation test on android emulator using appium. Browser in   emulator is not opening when it is automated via code. I have copied my code below kindly look into it and help me out. Thanks in advance

```
package report;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;  

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;  
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;  
import org.testng.annotations.Test;  


public class emulator {
WebDriver driver;

public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException 
{
DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"browser");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION,"4.4");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM,"windows");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("devices","Android");
capabilities.setCapability("avd","nexus");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.browser");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",    "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}



public void cal(){
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException
{
emulator a=new emulator();
a.setUp();
a.cal();           
}
}
```

Comment: What error or exception you are getting?

Comment: I am getting this error "An operation did not complete before its timeout expired. (Original error: timeout: Adb command timed out after 30 seconds"

Comment: Yes this is because default android emulator takes too much time to open and load. Please try with real device or Genymotion emulator..

Comment: I could open my emulator automatically but the script unable to initiate as per my requirement ie the browser not opening.

Comment: As I told , default emulators are too slow.

Answer (score 5):

The lock screen will  deactivate the other script of our program. So I tried open the emulator manually and disable the lock screen (Settings -> Security -> None). Then close the emulator. Now open the emulator automatically and run the script.

```
public void setUp(int p) throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "browser");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "windows");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-" + p);
    capabilities.setCapability("devices", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("avd", "Nexus7");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.browser");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + this.port + "/wd/hub"), 
             capabilities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working on mobile browser we need not to pass all the above desiredcapabilities like apppackage and appactivitiy. You can check the details of required capabilities @ http://qaautomationcafe.blogspot.in/2015/09/mobile-web-automation-using-appium.html